# JAM 2005 Mathematics Question 7

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image]

This is a multiple-choice question having only a single correct option that appeared in JAM 2005 (an Exam in India). Now according to me options B, C, and D all should be correct but only option D is marked as correct. My reasoning behind B, C and D is that:

$$ T(x) = cx, I(x) = x$$
$$ \therefore (T -cI)x = T(x) -cI(x)=cx-cx=0 $$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^3 $. Therefore rank of the transformation $(T-cI) $ should be the dimension of its image, which is the vector $0$. Hence the rank of the transformation is $0$. So B, C and D should all be correct. Where am I wrong?

Comment: We are given that there is a non-zero vector $x$ such that $T(x)=cx$, but we don't necessarily have $T(x)=cx$ for all $x$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\text{rank}(T-cI) = 3$, i.e. full rank, $(T-cI)$ is invertible and the only solution of $(T-cI)x = 0$ is $x = 0$. However, we are given a non-zero $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $x\in \ker(T-cI)$, i.e. $Tx = cx$ so $\text{rank}(T-cI) \neq 3$.

The rank may be $0,1$ or $2$ - we don't know what it is exactly! This is the best we can say when we are given the existence of **at least one** $x$ such that $Tx=cx$. If $Tx = cx$ happens **for all** $x$, then $(T-cI) = 0$ (the zero operator on $\mathbb{R}^3$) - but this isn't the case!

Answer (score 3):

AS J.W. Tanner said, we don't have $T(x)=cx$ for all $x$, but only for one.

Here the only thing you can say is $(T-cI)$ is not inversible because it is not injective, so its rank cannot be $3$.

But you can find $T$ such that its rank is $0$ (for instance $T=0$), or $1$ (for instance $T(x,y,z) = (x,y,0)$), or $2$ (for instance $T(x,y,z) = (x,0,0)$).

The concept behind this question is the one of eigenvalues.
cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors.